# Game Loop not executing

Tags: python

I am making a text-based game, and when I tried to debug it, my game loop was not executing. It just continues to allow me to move threw rooms when I wanted it to lead to a game over or to the end of the game. I'm unsure what I did wrong and was hoping someone could explain and help me fix it. Thank you!

```
def status():
    print('-' * 20)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room['name']))
    print('Your current inventory: {}\n'.format(inventory))
    if current_room['item']:
        print('Item in room: {}'.format(', '.join(current_room['item'])))
        print('')

        # data setup
        rooms = {'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'item': ['none'], 'south': 'Vendetta Room', 'east': 'Kitchen',
                                'north': 'Potion Lab', 'west': 'Armory',
                                'text': 'You are in the Great Hall.'},
                 'Armory': {'name': 'the Armory', 'item': ['fire Sword'], 'east': 'Great Hall', 'north': 'Treasure Room',
                            'text': 'You are in the Armory.'},
                 'Treasure Room': {'name': 'the Treasure Room', 'item': ['Magic Ring'], 'south': 'Armory',
                                   'text': 'You are in the Treasure Room.'},
                 'Potion Lab': {'name': 'the Potion Lab', 'item': ['Healing Potion'], 'east': 'Bedroom', 'south': 'Great Hall',
                                'text': 'You are in the Potion Lab.'},
                 'Bedroom': {'name': 'the Bedroom', 'item': ['Magic Key'], 'west': 'Potion Lab',
                             'text': 'You are in the Bedroom.'},
                 'Kitchen': {'name': 'the Kitchen', 'item': ['Sandwich'], 'south': 'Storage', 'west': 'Great Hall',
                             'text': 'You are in the Kitchen.'},
                 'Storage': {'name': 'Storage', 'item': ['Shield'], 'east': 'Mystery Room',
                             'text': 'You are in Storage.'},
                 'Mystery Room': {'name': 'the Mystery Room', 'item': ['none'], 'west': 'Storage', 'north': 'Kitchen',
                                  'text': 'You are in the Mystery Room.'},
                 # villain
                 'Vendetta Room': {'name': 'the Vendetta Room', 'item': ['none'], 'west': 'Dungeon', 'north': 'Great Hall',
                                   'text': 'You are in the Vendetta Room.'},
                 # Princess
                 'Dungeon': {'name': 'the Dungeon', 'item': ['none'], 'east': 'Vendetta Room',
                             'text': 'You are in the Dungeon.'}
                 }
        
        directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
        add_items = ['get item']
        current_room = rooms['Great Hall']
        inventory = []
        
        # game loop
        while True:
            if current_room['name'] == 'Mystery Room':
                if current_room['Magic Key'] not in inventory:
                    print("Oh No! As soon as you entered, the doors locked behind you.")
                    print("You don't have the Magic Key to open the door and end up trapped forever.")
                    print("GAME OVER")
                    break
                elif current_room['Magic Key'] not in inventory:
                    print("Oh No! As soon as you entered, the doors locked behind you.")
                    print("Luckily you found the Magic Key and could unlock the doors to continue your journey.")
            if current_room['name'] == 'the Vendetta Room' and len(inventory) > 5:
                print("You used all your items to defeat King Nox! Proceed to the next room to save the Princess.")
            elif current_room['name'] == 'the Vendetta Room' and len(inventory) < 6:
                print("You have found the Demon King but have no weapons.")
                print("You have been defeated and the Princess has perished.")
                print("GAME OVER")
                break
            elif current_room['name'] == 'the Dungeon':
                print('Congratulations! You have reached the Dungeon and saved the Princess!')
                print("You gave the Princess your healing potion and escorted her to the castle.")
                print("Thank you for playing!")
                break
    
    command = input('Enter Move:')
    
        # movement
        if command in directions:
            if command in current_room:
                current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
            elif command != rooms[current_room[command]] and command != add_items:
                # bad movement
                print('Invalid entry. Try again.')
                # quit game
        elif command == 'quit':
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            break
    
         # adding inventory
        if command in add_items:
            if command in add_items:
                if command == 'get item':
                    if current_room['item'] != 'none':
                        inventory.append(current_room['item'])
                        print("You acquired : ", current_room['item'])
                    elif current_room['item'] == 'none':
                        print("No items to collect in this room")
            elif command != add_items:
                print('Invalid entry. Try again.')
```

Comment: You really need to include the bit where user input is entered.  In the meantime, I assisted another user on a very similar version of this program.  Check out this link: [Room Exploration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73346078/room-exploration-issues-with-collecting-items-from-a-dictionary/73346773#73346773)

Comment: Your indentation here is not correct.  Since your "not ending" problem is likely related to indentation, please take some time to show us the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you included the entry of your commands, I gave the program a try.  The program failed on one occasion when an improper directional command was entered.  After testing it out, I made some minor corrections to allow the program to function in the spirit of the game.

```
# data setup
rooms = {'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'item': ['none'], 'south': 'Vendetta Room', 'east': 'Kitchen',
                        'north': 'Potion Lab', 'west': 'Armory',
                        'text': 'You are in the Great Hall.'},
         'Armory': {'name': 'the Armory', 'item': ['Fire Sword'], 'east': 'Great Hall', 'north': 'Treasure Room',
                    'text': 'You are in the Armory.'},
         'Treasure Room': {'name': 'the Treasure Room', 'item': ['Magic Ring'], 'south': 'Armory',
                           'text': 'You are in the Treasure Room.'},
         'Potion Lab': {'name': 'the Potion Lab', 'item': ['Healing Potion'], 'east': 'Bedroom', 'south': 'Great Hall',
                        'text': 'You are in the Potion Lab.'},
         'Bedroom': {'name': 'the Bedroom', 'item': ['Magic Key'], 'west': 'Potion Lab',
                     'text': 'You are in the Bedroom.'},
         'Kitchen': {'name': 'the Kitchen', 'item': ['Sandwich'], 'south': 'Storage', 'west': 'Great Hall',
                     'text': 'You are in the Kitchen.'},
         'Storage': {'name': 'Storage', 'item': ['Shield'], 'east': 'Mystery Room',
                     'text': 'You are in Storage.'},
         'Mystery Room': {'name': 'The Mystery Room', 'item': ['none'], 'west': 'Storage', 'north': 'Kitchen',
                          'text': 'You are in the Mystery Room.'},
         # villain
         'Vendetta Room': {'name': 'the Vendetta Room', 'item': ['none'], 'west': 'Dungeon', 'north': 'Great Hall',
                           'text': 'You are in the Vendetta Room.'},
         # Princess
         'Dungeon': {'name': 'the Dungeon', 'item': ['none'], 'east': 'Vendetta Room',
                     'text': 'You are in the Dungeon.'}
         }
        
directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
add_items  = ['get item']
current_room = rooms['Great Hall']
inventory = []

def status():
    print('-' * 20)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room['name']))
    print('Your current inventory: {}\n'.format(inventory))
    if current_room['item']:
        print('Item in room: {}'.format(', '.join(current_room['item'])))
        print('')
        
# game loop
while True:
    status()
    if current_room['name'] == 'The Mystery Room':
        if ['Magic Key'] not in inventory:
            print("Oh No! As soon as you entered, the doors locked behind you.")
            print("You don't have the Magic Key to open the door and end up trapped forever.")
            print("GAME OVER")
            break
        elif ['Magic Key'] in inventory:
            print("Oh No! As soon as you entered, the doors locked behind you.")
            print("Luckily you found the Magic Key and could unlock the doors to continue your journey.")
    if current_room['name'] == 'the Vendetta Room' and len(inventory) > 5:
        print("You used all your items to defeat King Nox! Proceed to the next room to save the Princess.")
    elif current_room['name'] == 'the Vendetta Room' and len(inventory) < 6:
        print("You have found the Demon King but have no weapons.")
        print("You have been defeated and the Princess has perished.")
        print("GAME OVER")
        break
    elif current_room['name'] == 'the Dungeon':
        print('Congratulations! You have reached the Dungeon and saved the Princess!')
        print("You gave the Princess your healing potion and escorted her to the castle.")
        print("Thank you for playing!")
        break
    
    command = input('Enter Move:')

    # movement
    if command == 'quit':           # Moved this ahead of the directional and acquisition commands
        print('Thanks for playing')
        break
    
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        elif command != add_items:
            # bad movement
            print('Invalid entry. Try again.')

    # adding inventory
    elif command in add_items:
        if current_room['item'] != ['none']:
            if current_room['item'] in inventory:   # No need to acquire an item a second time
                print("You already have this item")
            else:
                inventory.append(current_room['item'])
                print("You acquired : ", current_room['item'])
        elif current_room['item'] == ['none']:
            print("No items to collect in this room")            
    else:
        print('Invalid entry. Try again.')
```

I did a little rearranging of the code so that all of the data initialization appeared first, added in a call to the "status()" function in the "while" loop, moved the test for quitting before the directional and acquisition tests, and corrected the command check that was failing.  Also, I don't know if the game is supposed to allow for acquiring multiple quantities of any item (e.g. having 4 shields), so I added in a test for that.  If multiple quantities are allowed, you can remove that extra test.

Anyway, with that, I was able to save the princess.  Give that a try.

Comment: I am still can't get the 'Mystery room' if statement to run and if I enter a word that is not in the directions, the 'invalid entry' statement doesn't print. Everything else works great! the invalid entry statement, if I write 'elif command != directions:' would that work?

Comment: I had not focused on that bit.  I checked out what was happening and tweaked that test.  I updated the code in my answer to address that.  Note how the item and inventory values are wrapped inside "[]".  Also, I tweaked the command validation.  Give that a try.

Comment: You're welcome.  Enjoy!